# Access office URL through browser outside office

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I work as a web developer in a office. I have a linux machine as a work machine.
I develop code then test it on a browser. I can only access the URL that I use to test my pages inside my office.
I already have an reverse ssh on my office machine for me to access this machine from home, bypassing all the corporate firewalls. I can access and edit the files that I want.
But I still don't know how to access the office URL for testing the pages that I'm working on. What are my best options? X11 tunneling?
Can you give me some examples how I can achieve that?
I want the minimal bandwidth usage possible

Comment: X11 is irrelevant here (it would be useful to run a browser on your office machine and have it display at home but that would require a lot more bandwidth than forwarding the web traffic). I think you want a reverse SOCKS proxy (Google should help).

Comment: Either that or use port forwarding in `SSH`.  You can set it up so there's a port on your home machine that forwards through the `SSH` to the work machine which sends it to the internal web server.  If it's a dedicated server, this is easy.  If it uses the `Host:` field, you need to play with name resolution on your home machine.

Comment: Thank you both. I will google reverse SOCKS proxy, but @MAP how can I do that ssh? Can you give me some page that explains that. Thank you

Comment: It's a standard feature of the SSH protocol, see the manual for all the variations.  I thought to mention it because you already said you had SSH (actually you said "reverse SSH" and I have no idea what the adjective means in that context).  You can set up the SSH so that it accepts connections on one host and forwards them onto a port reachable through the other host.  You could use this, for example, to forward some port on your home machine to the web server at the office.